# Does anyone know the Reflection method in solving PDEs?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, reflection, separable-extension

I am looking at solutions for a diffusion equation, where we have:

\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{4}u_{xx}=u_t , \ \ \ \ \  \ \, 0<x<\infty, t>0 \\
u_x(0,t)=0 \\
u(x,0)=\begin{cases}
6 \ \ \ \ 0  \leq  x\leq 3\\
0 \ \ \ \ x>3
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Clearly, here the domain of x is infinite. A method which I am trying to understand is  using the "Reflection method" also called the "Odd  extension method". Here we form an extension, $u^\bullet$ of  $u$ as such

\begin{equation}
u^\bullet(x,t)= \begin{cases}
u(-x,t) \ \ \ \ x<0 \\
u(x,t) \ \ \ \ x>0
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

Then the method just refers to the "reflection lemma" which yields the following new form of the original PDE:

\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
u^\bullet_t-\frac{1}{4}u^\bullet_{xx}=\big(u_t-\frac{1}{4}u_{xx}\big)^\bullet-2\cdot\frac{1}{4}u_x(0,t)\delta(x)=0\\
u^\bullet(x,0)=\begin{cases}
6 \ \ \  for |x|<3 \overset{def}{=}g(x)\\
0 \ \ \  for |x|>3
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
\end{equation}

which can be subjected to Laplace transform, and then get a solution in terms of the error function (which is *really* laborious).

But I have no literature of this reflection method, and no example which clearly illustrates how to derive that new form of the original PDE.

Does anyone have an idea how that form came about?

Thanks

Comment: I think what is meant is: if you want to solve $u(x)$ for $x>0$ with an initial condition $f(x)$ and Neumann condition $\partial_x u(0,t)=0$, you may instead solve a different problem- the one for $u(x)$ on $-\infty <x<\infty$ with initial condition $f(|x|)$ and no Neumann condition at $x=0$. Notice that on $x>0$ the solutions to the two problems are identical

Comment: I see. But I still do not understand  where that term with the delta function comes from

Comment: I don't think the term with the delta contributes at all because $u_x(0,t)=0$. Let $v(x,t)=H(x)u(x,t)+H(-x)u(-x,t)$, which is your $u^\bullet$. $H$ is Heaviside's step function. Then apply the operator $\partial_t-\frac{1}{4}\partial_{xx}$ to $v$. What remains is the heat equation plus the term involving the delta.

Comment: Yes, but where does the delta come from? The only thing with delta I know of, is the Fourier transform of a constant, Q, that would give $2\pi Q\delta(\omega)$ . But here we don't have Fourier transform, though we could indeed, but that would be a different approach.

Comment: Ah, the distributional derivative of $H$ is $\delta$

Comment: Thanks, I think this question has been solved now, though this method seems to foggy. I prefer the Fourier transform.

Comment: Using Laplace transform wasn't really required for this method, and the expression involving the $\delta$ seems a bit unnecessary- the important thing is that you can solve a problem on $x>0$ by relating it to a problem on $-\infty <x<\infty$

Comment: Yes, however, this solving on the infinite rod requires either Fourier transform and use the heat transfer kernels and convolution, though you end up with an integral, or you can do this http://sites.oxy.edu/vgrigoryan/342/syllabus.pdf

Comment: Assuming the function derivative in $x$ at $x=0$ is $0$ would correspond to an even extension, rather than an odd one. An odd extension would correspond to the case where the function value at $x=0$ would be $0$.

Comment: Yes, given that these are Neumann conditions.